# How to pass argument to broadcast receiver from an activity that call a service

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-intent, broadcastreceiver

Hey I want to pass an argument to the broadcast receiver. 
Here is the scenario:
In an activity when i press a button it will call a service that service will call BroadCastReceiver.
Now i want to pass a parameter from the activity to service which will in turn pass same data to the BroadCastreceiver

Is it possible...?

Comment: You can pass it using `Intent`

Comment: Thanks, Yeah i Passed using intent but i will show null Here is the link for it. https://github.com/sudikrt/InstaPo/tree/master/InstaPo/app/src/main/java/com/geekyint/instapo    In this i want to send some data from MainActivity to LocationReceiver. This LocationReceiver is called by the service BackgroundLocation.java .      So the process is that when MainActivity call the service with some data which in turn pass same along with other content to LocationReceiver, which is the broadCastReceiver

Comment: In `MainActivity`, you're passing `data_1`  to `BackgroundLocation` service, but there you don't recover the `data_1` extra data. You should get this extra and pass it in  `BackgroundLocation:246`.

Comment: I m not getting you.

Answer (score 0):

Pass it using the intent that you use to start the service.

Incidentally, what do you mean by "call the broadcast receiver?" You should never directly call a Broadcast Receiver - they're just for handling broadcasts (events). With that said, if you're just sending a broadcast, you can include the data in that intent.

Comment: Thanks, Yeah i Passed using intent but i will show null Here is the link for it. https://github.com/sudikrt/InstaPo/tree/master/InstaPo/app/src/main/java/com/geekyint/instapo In this i want to send some data from MainActivity to LocationReceiver. This LocationReceiver is called by the service BackgroundLocation.java . So the process is that when MainActivity call the service with some data which in turn pass same along with other content to LocationReceiver, which is the broadCastReceiver